# Implementing tables and database in .exe file with PyInstaller

Tags: database, sqlite, pyinstaller, kivymd

I created SPEC file with PyInstaller and then modified it to include .db file with 2 tables in .exe file:

a=Analysis(...
datas=[('xx.kv', '.'), ('xx.ico', '.'), ('xx.jpg', '.'), ('gwords.db', '.')],...)

.exe file is created and app is running as it should be, but .db file is created only after running app and inside of it there are no tables. I assume I should modify SPEC file in some other manner? *Database is sqlite3 with kivymd 2.0.1

(1) I tried to implement database.db in SPEC file as it's seen in question but no luck.
(2) I tried to implement database python code inside app python code so that tables are generated after running app but the problem is I couldn't get tables to be written once and that's it or that values inside are ignored if duplicates. So, no luck there also.